# „Und so weiter und so fort“ vs. „Und so weiter“

Tags: difference, meaning

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden Sätzen?

> 1. Ich besuche Nürnberg, München, Berlin, Augsburg und so weiter und so fort.
> 2. Ich besuche  Nürnberg, München, Berlin, Augsburg und so weiter.

Hat es etwas mit der Reihenfolge der Städte zu tun? Oder bedeutet der erste Satz, dass ich den Besuch der Städte als Reihe wiederhole?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Deutsche hat mehrere verschiedene Floskeln, mit denen man die Fortsetzung einer Aufzählung andeuten kann:

- und so weiter (Abkürzung usw.)
- und so fort (Abkürzung usf.)
- etcetera (Abkürzung etc.; Lateinisch für "und weitere")
- pp (veraltet; eigentlich Abkürzung für Lateinisch "perge perge" = "fahre fort, fahre fort"; wird aber immer "pe pe" ausgesprochen)

In der Regel benutzt man hauptsächlich *usw.*, in der Schriftsprache gelegentlich auch *etc.* oder noch seltener *usf.*. Manche Autoren wechseln zwischen diesen verschiedenen Abkürzungen ab, um nicht immer wieder dieselbe zu verwenden. Einen Bedeutungsunterschied scheint es gar nicht zu geben.

Um besondere Aufmerksamkeit auf die Fortsetzung einer Reihe zu richten, ist es als besonderes Stilmittel auch möglich, zwei (oder selten auch mehr) solche Fortsetzungsanzeiger hintereinander zu gebrauchen. Üblich sind dabei die folgenden Kombinationen:

- usw. usw.
- usw. usf.
- usf. usf.
- etc. etc.
- etc. pp
- usw. usf. etc. pp

Dieses Stilmittel wird häufiger in der Umgangssprache als in der Schriftsprache verwendet. Meist wird damit Unwillen über das Aufgezählte ausgedrückt.

Beispiel:

> Ich besuche Nürnberg, München, Berlin, Augsburg und so weiter. Das sind alles Städte, die ich schon lange kennenlernen wollte.
>
> Ich besuche Nürnberg, München, Berlin, Augsburg und so weiter und so fort. Es sieht so aus, als ob diese Reise nie enden würde. Ich war schon seit drei Monaten nicht mehr zu Hause, und es ist kein Ende abzusehen. Kaum habe ich eine Stadt abgehakt, sind auch schon zwei neue auf der Liste.

---

Im Französischen gibt es dieses Phänomen überhaupt nicht. Es hat neben *etc.* nur das seltener gebrauchte *et ainsi de suite*. An Stelle von Verdopplungen gibt es anders gebildete Ausdrücke mit ähnlicher Funktion:

- et j'en passe
- et patati et patata
- et tout le bataclan

Das Englische steht hier zwischen dem Französischen und dem Deutschen. Es bietet die Wahl zwischen *and so on*, *and so forth* und *etc.* Eine Fortsetzung betonen kann man analog zum Deutschen oder analog zum Französischen:

- and so on and so forth
- and what have you
- and all the rest of it
- yadda-yadda-yadda

Answer (score 10):

Die Bedeutung ist gleich. Allerdings ist *und so weiter und so fort*  umgangssprachlich und wird eher spaßig oder als Stilmittel für eine Monotonie eingesetzt. *Und so weiter* ist neutral und kann immer verwendet werden.

*Und so fort* alleine ist äquivalent zu *und so weiter*, wird aber eher selten verwendet.

Comment: Als Stilmittel für Monotonie ist richtig, würde ich sagen, aber spaßig?

Comment: Damit meinte ich, dass es manchmal, z.B. selbstironisch, bei Erzählungen eingeschoben wird.

Comment: Kann denn 'und so weiter' alleine nicht (selbst-?) ironisch verwendet werden?

Comment: Natürlich, aber genauso ein langgezogenes "und so weiter".

Comment: Es ist also kein Unterscheidungsmerkmal, ob man 'und so fort' verwendet. Ironie kann man mit als auch ohne ausdrücken und beide Formen können auch unironisch sein?

Comment: Ja, aber "und so weiter und so fort" hat zumindest für mich schon einen witzelnden oder zumindest stark umgangssprachlichen Beigeschmack.

Comment: @Œlrim Dem stimme ich zu. Die Floskel "Und so weiter und so fort" empfinde ich als die leichte Steigerungsform zu "Und so weiter". Wenn jemand die lange Form benutzt, verschiebt sich der Schwerpunkt des Satz vom der reinen Aufzählung hin zur Betonung der Monotonie

Answer (score 0):

It is very much like the English phrase "so on and so forth":

> I have visited Berlin, Munich, Stuttgart and so on.
>   I have visited Berlin, Munich, Stuttgart and so on and so forth.

"Und so fort" is just an extension of the fact that you have continued an action.